# Delphi : Select into outfile using parameter

Tags: mysql, delphi, mariadb

I am trying to use a `Select Into Outfile` command in Delphi using MySQL:

```
dirfile:=pathProg+SaveDialog1.FileName+'.csv';

With dm.Query
do 
    begin
    SQL.Clear;
    SQL.Text:='SELECT * FROM tabel1  INTO OUTFILE :parfile';
    Parameters.ParamByName('parfile').value:=dirfile;
    ExecSQL;
    end;
```

But it doesn't work, it returns an eror:

> you have error in your sql syntax check the manual that corresponds to your mariadb server version for the right syntakx to use near

Is there any suggestion to solve this?

Comment: All examples I can find of `INTO OUTFILE` use a hard-coded filename string.  Are you sure an input parameter is valid to use here?  Not only that, all documentation I can find for `INTO OUTFILE` say the output file is created on the DB server, and that `FILE` permissions are required to use `INTO OUTFILE`.  Do you have that permission?  Specifying a path that is local to the client app is not going to be valid unless the client and server are on the same machine.

Comment: If i change the parameter to filename string  'Select * from table1 INTO OUTFILE "D:\file1.csv"' it's work fine. I think the problem is using parameter... Is there any option beside using parameter ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching around, it turns out you **cannot** use a parameterized value for the filename, it must be a string literal.  In this case, you will have to build up the SQL string manually instead, eg:

```
dirfile:=pathProg+SaveDialog1.FileName+'.csv';

with dm.Query do 
begin
  SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM tabel1 INTO OUTFILE ' + QuotedStr(dirfile);
  ExecSQL;
end;
```